# App Store Rejection (App store rejected App because of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key)

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, capability, info-plist

Dec 18, 2018 at 10:34 AM
From Apple
2. 3 Performance: Accurate Metadata
Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

We were unable to install the app on iPad. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an iPad.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

Resources

Please review the Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key for information on the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the "Declaring the Required Device Capabilities" section of the App Programming Guide for iOS.

i have one key armv7 in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array in info.plist for all my targets and minimum ios version is set to 11.0, Supported Architectures : armv7, arm64 ,armv7s Required Capabilities : armv7 , App-Version : 1.0

Now, i am using coreLocation Services for google map to find the lat- long of a place in the app. Do i need to add the location-services key also and will it help.

Thanks

Comment: Our app works great on an iPad with the `armv7` in the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, so are you sure that you only have `armv7` there? Seems to to be an other restriction there.

Comment: Yes I am sure  UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities  have value armv7..in info.plist